# How to find records which ALL values in column are contained in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have such tables:

```
Table1

ID | Name
---------
1    Name1
2    Name2
3    Name3


Table2

ID | FindID Table1ID 
--------------------
1     1       1
2     2       1
3     1       2
4     2       2
5     1       3
6     2       3
7     3       3
8     1       4


Table3

ID
--
1
2
```

What I need to do - I need to find all Table 1 Ids which have in Table 2  all Table 3 values as FindId column's values .
For example, if in Table 3 we have 1 and 2, in result it should return

```
Result
ID
-----
1
2
3
```

Because Table1.Id = 1 have 1 and 2 in Table 2, same for Table1.Id = 2, and Table1.Id = 3 have 1,2,3.
Table1.Id = 4 has only 1, so it isn't contained in results.

If in Table 3 we have 1,2,3 - then only Table1.Id = 3 will be returned.

I've tried something like

```
        SELECT distinct t1.id FROM Table1 t1
        join Table2 t2 on t2.Table1Id = t1.ID
        join Table3 t3 on t3.Id = t2.FindId
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: "If in Table 3 we have 1,2,3 - then only Table1.Id = 3 will be returned." do you mean in result set only 3 will be present ?

Comment: @Jfrd yes, you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all `table2.table1id` that have all the `findId`s in `table3`.  If so, aggregation should do what you want:

```
select t2.table1id
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t3
     on t2.findid = t3.id
group by t2.table1id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from table3);
```

Comment: What if we have in table2 for ID = 1 values with FindId = 1,2,3, and in Table3 will be tree records = 2,3,4?  Will the counter work in this case?

Comment: @AtlasPromotion . . . It would work with the `join`.  "4" would not match so no rows would match.